# IBM Cloud: How to enable App ID for app on Kubernetes cluster with K8s Ingress and ALB OAuth Proxy?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, ibm-appid

I am trying to configure App ID-based authentication for an app deployed to IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service (IKS) running in a VPC. In the past it worked well with [IBM's own Ingress](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-kube-auth#configuring-ingress). However, that has been deprecated. Now, I am following the [guide here which is using the community Ingress and talks about adding IBM App Id](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-comm-ingress-annotations#app-id).

I seem to have configured everything, but the host / site cannot be reached. Here is how the Ingress resource looks like:

```
"apiVersion": "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "kind": "Ingress",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "public-iks-k8s-nginx",
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin": "https://$host/oauth2-myappid/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri",
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url": "https://$host/oauth2-myappid",
            "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet": "auth_request_set $access_token $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
        access_by_lua_block {
         if ngx.var.access_token ~= \"\" then
           ngx.req.set_header(\"Authorization\", \"Bearer \" .. ngx.var.access_token)
         end
        }
        "
        },
        "name": "ingress-for-mytest",
        "namespace": "sfs"
    },
    "spec": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "host": "myhost.henrik-cluster-cd5d3f574d7d8057a176af82152f5-0000.eu-de.containers.appdomain.cloud",
                "http": {
                    "paths": [
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "my-service",
                                "servicePort": 8081
                            },
                            "path": "/"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "tls": [
            {
                "hosts": [
                    "myhost.henrik-cluster-cd5d3f574d7d8057a176af82152f5-0000.eu-de.containers.appdomain.cloud"
                ],
                "secretName": "henrik-cluster-cd5d3f574d7d8057a176af82152f5-0000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with the following definition:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-for-mytest
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "public-iks-k8s-nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2-myappid/auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://$host/oauth2-myappid/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      auth_request_set $access_token $upstream_http_x_auth_request_access_token;
      auth_request_set $id_token $upstream_http_authorization;
      access_by_lua_block {
        if ngx.var.id_token ~= "" and ngx.var.access_token ~= "" then
          ngx.req.set_header("Authorization", "Bearer " .. ngx.var.access_token .. " " .. ngx.var.id_token:match("%s*Bearer%s*(.*)"))
        end
      }
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost
    secretName: ingress-secret-for-mytest
  rules:
  - host: myhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port: 
              number: 8081
```

It is important to note that the OAuth2 proxy (see the [steps regarding the proxy add-on and App ID integration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-comm-ingress-annotations#app-id)) will only deploy successfully to a non-default Kubernetes namespace if the (cluster) Ingress secret is copied into that namespace.

You can find the Ingress secret using the following command and watching for the secret in the default namespace:

```
ibmcloud ks ingress secret ls -c your-cluster-name
```

Thereafter, (re)create that secret in the non-default namespace, copying the CRN and name of that secret:

```
ibmcloud ks ingress secret create -c your-cluster-name -n your-namespace
    --cert-crn the-crn-shown-in-the-output-above --name the-secret-name-shown-above
```